# Converting Binary to Decimal using a text file

Tags: java, binary, text-files

I'm creating a program made up of two java files. The first one involves creating a class that accepts a binary from the user and returns its decimal value. The second involves creating a class that reads a list of binary strings from a text file and writes their decimal values to the console. This class should call methods from the first java class in order to achieve its tasks, and should be able to indicate if one of the strings in this file is not binary.

I have the first java class completed, but I'm having difficulty on the second, specifically on how I can get the program to read each individual  String from the text file and then either print out their values or declare that they are not a binary. I also need some help on how to call methods from the first class. Could someone help lead me in the right direction?

Here are both codes:

Class 1:

```
import java.util.*;
public class BinaryDecoder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Enter a binary: ");
        String binary = input.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("---------------");
        
        boolean isBinary = binaryDetector(binary);
        
        if(isBinary) {
            int count = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<binary.length(); i++) {
                if(binary.charAt(i) != ' ') {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            int binarySize = Integer.valueOf(count);
            System.out.println("Binary size: " + binarySize);
            
            int decimalValue = binaryToDecimal(binary);
            
            System.out.println("Value = " + decimalValue);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Not a binary");
        }
        
    }
    
    public static boolean binaryDetector(String x) {
        int copyOfInput = Integer.valueOf(x);
        
        while(copyOfInput != 0) {
            if(copyOfInput % 10 > 1) {
                return false;
            }
            copyOfInput = copyOfInput/10;
        }
        return true;
        }
    
    public static int binaryToDecimal(String n) {
        String num = n;
        int dec_value = 0;
        
        int base = 1;
        
        int len = num.length();
        for(int i = len - 1; i>= 0; i--) {
            if(num.charAt(i) == '1') {
                dec_value += base;
            }
            base = base * 2;
        }
        return dec_value;
    }

}
```

Class 2

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BinaryToDecimalTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("Strings.txt"));
        while(inFile.hasNext()) {
            String inString = inFile.next();
}
}
}
```

And let's say for reference that the text file has these numbers in it:

```
1011010011101
1011101110101
1201234000100
1234456000110
1011010100011
```

Please let me know if you need any more clarification or information. Thank you all very much!

Comment: My updated answer may help solve  your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use methods from BinaryDecoder in  BinaryToDecimalTester you will have to import them. The best way would be to declare package in each class and import that using it, for example
Decoder class:

```
package binarynumbers;

import java.util.*;
public class BinaryDecoder {

public static void main(String[] args) { ...
```

and then import specific ( or all ) methods in BinaryToDecimalTester:

```
package stackoverflow;


import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

import static stackoverflow.BinaryDecoder.binaryToDecimal;

public class BinaryToDecimalTester { ...
```

importing it this way lets you use it normally as you woud expect :

```
System.out.println(binaryToDecimal(inString));
```

Concept of packages and imports is more complicated than this and essential to writing programs.

As to reading each individual line as String from the text file and processing it your class is sufficient, FileInputReader is one of another options to read from file. My example would be this:

```
package binarynumbers;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

import static binarynumbers.BinaryDecoder.binaryToDecimal;
import static binarynumbers.BinaryDecoder.binaryDetector;

public class BinaryToDecimalTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Strings.txt"));
    String line = "";

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        System.out.println(binaryDetector(line));
        System.out.println(binaryToDecimal(line));
    }
}
}
```

in terms of implementing method detecting binary numbers I can suggest this [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-a-number-is-binary-or-not-in-java/)

Comment: Importing the methods from BinaryDecoder.java worked, but using the BufferedReader has not helped. I keep getting an error message. I did add System.out.println(binaryToDecimal(inString)) to my original code and it prints out the decimal value for each number; however, I need to figure out what to do to make sure the ones that aren't binary are labelled as such ("Not binary").

Comment: I've added link to implementation of such method

Answer (score 0):

You have to select which class should be your main.

If you keep 2 as your main and then instead of main in 1 you can read both files in 2 and used the static methods you have created in 1 by importing them in 2.

import BinaryDecoder.binaryToDecimal;

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you do the check for a binary digit as you try to convert the value.  Then throw an exception and print the message if the digit is not binary.

There is no need to first check and then convert the value.

Here is an easy way to do the conversion.

```
public static int binaryToDecimal(String n) {
   int val = 0;
   for(char c : n.toCharArray()) {
       if (c != '1' && c != '0') {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("Number not binary");
       }
       val = val*2;
       val += c-'0';
   }
   return val;
}
```

Now all you need to do is read in the values and call the method.  In lieu of the exception you could also return an optional.

```
public static OptionalInt binaryToDecimal(String n) {
   int val = 0;
   for(char c : n.toCharArray()) {
       if (c != '1' && c != '0') {
           return OptionalInt.empty();
       }
       val = val*2;
       val += c-'0';
   }
   return OptionalInt.of(val);
}
```

Now just check to see if the returned `Optional` is empty before you print the result.  To read in the values from a file, I  would recommend using a scanner instance.  Here is an example using the data mentioned in your question along with the required imports.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.OptionalInt;
import java.util.Scanner;

try (Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("f:/numbers.txt"))) {
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        String str = input.nextLine();
        OptionalInt op = binaryToDecimal(str);
        System.out.printf("%s -> %s%n", str, op.isPresent() ?
                op.getAsInt() : "Non binary string");
    }
} catch (IOException ie) {
    ie.printStackTrace();
}
```

prints

```
1011010011101 -> 5789
1011101110101 -> 6005
1201234000100 -> Non binary string
1234456000110 -> Non binary string
1011010100011 -> 5795
```